# Loading an NSArray from a .plist file

Tags: arrays, xcode, null, plist

OK, so I know this question seems really basic, but I can't find a solution to my problem anywhere -

I have a .plist file within my project entitled 'feelings'. My plist file reads:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>feelings</key>
    <array>
        <string>Happy</string>
        <string>Sad</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In the .m file under -(void)ViewDidLoad; I am trying to retrieve the contents of the plist using the following code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"feelings" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

self.feelingsArray = tempArray;
[tempArray release];
```

However I don't seem to be loading the array from the .plist file and executing the following code:

```
NSLog(@"feelings: %@", feelings);
```

returns `(null)`

Can anyone figure out where I'm going wrong? It all seems fine to me, from what I've worked on before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't read from plist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275502/cant-read-from-plist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top-level of the plist file is a dictionary, not an array. You should use `NSDictionary` instead of `NSArray`:

```
NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.feelingsArray = [tempDict objectForKey:@"feelings"];
[tempDict release];
```

Comment: I could kiss you both - thank you! any idea though why XCode generates each plist as a NSDictionary base? I set my first row entry as an array with happy and sad as it's 2 objects.

Comment: you could also change the top-level object to an array.

Comment: As suggested by Richard, changing your top-level plist entry to be an <array> should allow your original code to work.

Answer (score 3):

It returns a dictionary object not array,

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"feelings" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"Feelings: %@",tempDict);
[tempDict release];
```