# Read Mutable Array from File / Plist

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Here is my problem. I show files out of an MutableArray in a UITableView with UISearchBar.

Therefore I made an Array:

```
allTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
               [[CRFParts alloc] initWithName:@"ABC" andDescription:@"DEF"],
               [[CRFParts alloc] initWithName:@"GHI" andDescription:@"JKL"],
                nil];
```

I have round about 2000 lines of this. I build me simple strings out of an excel file but the code inside my .m is huge than. Is there a possibility to read these content out of an file (plist/txt)?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Yes you can. There are plenty of example reading a plist file...

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758305/reading-plist-file/). It has a lot of good code on how to read a plist and dictionaries vs arrays.

And next time, search before you ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can easely use:
`NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];`
or
 `NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];`

Check out [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithContentsOfURL:) on the topic. 
Be careful on what structure you are loading as a plist can represent and array or a dictionary at its root. [Other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338531/loading-an-nsarray-from-a-plist-file) about it